# domain-based routing with systemd-resolved

Tags: dns, systemd

I know this has been discussed many times, also on this forum, but I still haven't been able to get a complete answer.
I'm trying to use a certain DNS server when resolving a certain domain.
What I've tried thus far:

```
cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network

[Match]
Name=*

[Network]
DNS=10.96.0.10
Domains=~cluster.local
```

The problem with this configuration is that all but the link I'm interested in (eth0 - link 2) are being set as I want it to:

```
Global: 10.0.0.126
Link 13 (vxlan.calico):
Link 12 (cali8263d13a54d): 10.96.0.10
Link 9 (calia1d7a43e746): 10.96.0.10
Link 8 (cali29e422b71fc): 10.96.0.10
Link 7 (cali758004a940e): 10.96.0.10
Link 6 (calif05b5957d52): 10.96.0.10
Link 5 (cali306363bfd09): 10.96.0.10
Link 4 (cali56b877defb5): 10.96.0.10
Link 3 (docker0):
Link 2 (eth0): 10.0.0.126
```

The interesting part is that running it from the command line works:

```
systemd-resolve --set-dns=10.96.0.10 --set-domain=cluster.local --interface=eth0
```

```
resolvectl dns
Global: 10.0.0.126
Link 13 (vxlan.calico):
Link 12 (cali8263d13a54d): 10.96.0.10
[..]
Link 4 (cali56b877defb5): 10.96.0.10
Link 3 (docker0):
Link 2 (eth0): 10.96.0.10
```

So basically I'm trying to translate that command into a proper configuration.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I know for a fact it is possible using dnsmasq though.

Comment: Well then how is it possible then to achieve this through the command line by using exactly systemd-resolved? I'm basically asking to translate the cli into  a proper configuration.
And how do you explain this works for all the other links?
I know you can use dnsmasq, unbound or some other dns server. But that's not the point, I want to use it with linux's core tools.

Answer (score 2):

I got my VirtulBox host based network setup working with this post. Here is how:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/milkiway.conf
[Resolve]
DNSStubListenerExtra=192.168.56.1

# cat /etc/systemd/network/vboxnet0.network 
[Match]
Name=vboxnet0

[Network]
DNS=192.168.56.10
DNS=192.168.56.20
Domains=~milkyway.site

# resolvectl query earth.milkyway.site
earth.milkyway.site: 192.168.56.10             -- link: vboxnet0
```

Comment: I should have been more precise in my question, I understand now. The problem is that systemd-resolved doesn't seem to be capable of domain-based routing independently of the network connections/interfaces like dnsmasq can. I've ended up using dnsmasq actually. So in this case networkd forces you to match a network interface and apply the settings for the whole interface. Not fun unfortunately. Can be useful when you use VPNs (which is a separate connection), for example, sure.